# Color enhancement using PIL: How to compute color value?

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, python-imaging-library, histogram-equalization

I am using these functions to modify the values of brightness, contrast and sharpness. My default values are 128, 24, 4 respectively. I extracted these values. I don't know how to extract the value of the color to modify it in the same way.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

def brightness_enhancer(img, br):
 img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 img = Image.fromarray(img)
 enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img)
 factor = 128/br
 return enhancer.enhance(factor)

def contrast_enhancer(img, ct):
 #img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 #img = Image.fromarray(img)
 enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img)
 factor = 24/ct
 return enhancer.enhance(factor)

def sharpness_enhancer(img, sh):
 #img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 #img = Image.fromarray(img)
 enhancer = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(img)
 factor = 4/sh
 return enhancer.enhance(factor)

def color_enhancer(img):
 #img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 #img = Image.fromarray(img)
 enhancer = ImageEnhance.Color(img)
 factor = 0.5 #enhancement of the image
 return enhancer.enhance(factor)
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, please? You don't call or use any of the functions you have defined. You seem to be mixing up PIL with OpenCV - why would you do that? I'm not criticising, just trying to understand so I, and others can assist you better. Thank you.

Comment: My only request is to understand how I can extract the value of "Color", which belongs to PIL library. This to handle it, so I can obtain yellowed images. The script is only to see my functions. I obtained the values for sharpness, contrast and brightness from other functions . But I don't know how to extract that particular "color" value which can be manipulate by the function "ImageEnhance.Color". I used previously CV2 for other image processings.

Comment: Maybe the correct request is: HOW CAN I EXTRACT A SINGLE VALUE REFERRED TO THE SATURATION OF THE IMAGE?

Comment: Should I convert RGB image into HSV image and then obtain the mean value of the saturation between all pixels?

Comment: Sorry, I really can't deduce what you are trying to do. You show 4 functions,  you call none of them and you want to what the saturation of some unspecified image is?

Comment: saturation = hsv_img[:,:,1]

np.mean(saturation)

Comment: Is this the correct way to extract the average saturation of an image?

Comment: It's probably correct but you haven't said what you are trying to achieve yet, so it is potentially not of much use to you.

Comment: I have a dataset composed of images and I have to equalize images so I can compare them